# Can I find the users who view specific question

Tags: support

---

[image] Can I find the viewers  for specific question?

[image]

For example, I can see 5 views for a question. Now I have the question id, so can I get all the users who viewed this question?

I looked at https://api.stackexchange.com/, but I wasn't able find out if it's possible or not. And I tried data queries also. my question is, it possible to find the users who visit a specific question?

**i'm sorry guys for asking this**

Comment: I doubt the data is even stored in the database. And what about logged out users? And no, I don't want people chasing after me saying, "u saw my question, y u no answer?"

Comment: what do you mean by "what about logged out users"

Comment: Users who are not logged in have no identity on SE.

Comment: no no i don't want to find non identity users .only logged in users

Comment: Give one reason why you want to know who views your question, because I don't find it useful.

Comment: @AndrewT. 'i'm going to devalop app for detect who the $#$#434 downvote my questions.to do that first i wanna find who view .then i know rest of things

Comment: @whiletrue: voting is anonymous. You will not get that data. And it is completely pointless to try and get it. What would you do with that info? Go and revenge downvote everyone?

Comment: @Mat no no i will never revenge because i don't want to downvte but what i want ask "why did you downvote ?give me the reason " and i don't want to to this very hardly.but i just ask is there any simple way using queries.if not no problem

Comment: If the downvoter didn't leave a comment, they didn't feel like giving you a reason. And you chasing after them will most likely not help at all. Just forget about this, it is a waste of your time.

Comment: @Mat yeah! yeah! yeah! i'm agree with you

Comment: I downvoted because of the gif.  Actually, I didn't downvote.  But it did cause me to punch myself repeatedly in the face because you were not immediately available.

Comment: @Will keep the calm and love the gif

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you can't. One very important reason for this is exactly to prevent what you said you wanted to do in the comments: it is to prevent revealing the identity of voters. When someone gets a downvote, the person whose post was downvoted could query who viewed the question to narrow down who might have downvoted.

**For every case where getting clarification would actually be a fruitful enterprise, there are dozens of cases where it would be pointless.** I'm not kidding. Every now and then someone comes on Meta saying they're just seeking clarification and they're ready to listen. **I believe them**. The problem is not *them* but all the *others*.

For instance, take the person who posts "Is there a tool that..." or ask for career advice, or posted only an error message without context. Either they did not read or understand the instructions regarding what and how to ask, or understood them but decided to go ahead anyway. In the former case, all will be clarified for them when they see the close reason on their post. In the latter case, what can I say that will make them see the light?

Comment: Your answer made this post worth _viewing_

Comment: Down voted because your ratio of fruitful: pointless is *way off*. It should be more like 1:1000, at least. :p